# Stop images resizing div when browser changes size

Tags: html, css, image, header, image-size

i have put my site in dropbox so you can see it
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13722201/Dorset%20Designs/home.html

when i resize my browser the top div #header expands below my navigation bar and i want it to stay flush, but i still want the images to adjust size

sorry about the messy code

thanks in advance

arran, 16

Comment: You want what to stay flush where?

Comment: when you resize the browser the header overflows into the body. please can you stop it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a super simple fix, you just need to define the width of your divs in css.

Comment: ill give it a try, but how does the width affect the height ?

Comment: That's a good question, html isn't normally like that but the slider you are using, Nivoslider, it's a feature they built in so that the slider will always be proportioned properly.

Comment: What works for me is to define the width as Cleverbot said and then to set margin-left: and margin-right: to "auto"

Answer (score 0):

Remove the width: 100% and height: auto from the images and give them a fixed height, equivalent to the distance between the top of the frame and the top of the navigation bar.

For example, changing `#webdesign` to just `height:95px` fixes the image's dimensions.

Comment: The main picture below the nav will still be fluid. There's no point making the images a dynamic size depending on the viewport size because the nav bar is a fixed distance away from the top of the frame. If you want it to resize with the browser window you'd have to work out what you want the minimum and maximum height of your header to be and use JavaScript to change it's height depending on the window height.

Comment: so if i make them fixed how can i stop them moving ?

Comment: If you mean how do you stop them moving from side to side on a horizontal resize, you'd have to make their containing div a fixed width.